# Serillog v2.3.0 throws compile error for PermitCrossAppDomainCalls

Tags: c#, logging, nuget-package, serilog

My app is currently using Serilog version 1.5 for logging and we have decided to upgrade to Serilog 2.3.0. When upgrading am running into a compile time error for PermitCrossAppDomainCalls. Any ideas if the property is supported in Serilog v2.3?

**Error Line:**
LogContext.PermitCrossAppDomainCalls = true;

**Error Message**
'Serilog.Context.LogContext' does not contain a definition for 'PermitCrossAppDomainCalls'

Answer (score 0):

This setting is no longer required by Serilog 2.0 - the functionality it enables will "just work". You can safely remove the call to the property setter.